# Typing D3 line.defined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm drawing a line that might contain gaps using `line.defined()`, but I can't figure out how to type it properly. My graph displays as expected. Here's the code:

```
interface XYPoint {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface XYPointNullable {
  x: number;
  y: number | null;
}

const lineIWantToDraw: XYPointNullable[] = [{ x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: null }];

const createLine = line<XYPointNullable>() // <- type error here
  .defined(d => d.y !== null)
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y);
```

With the above code, I get an error `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'`.

If I type the line fn as `XYPoint`, I get an error `Argument of type 'XYPointNullable[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'XYPoint[]'` when calling the function.

Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that `d => d.y` always returns a number, you can cast it as such:

```js
interface XYPointNullable {
  x: number;
  y: number | null;
}

line<XYPointNullable>()
  .defined(d => d.y !== null)
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y as number);
```

[This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgG2AOwKZwL5wGZQQhwBEAJgMwC0AzgBYCGYGJA3AFDvowZR4MBjLAA0AmgAUI3AHIBXZMgYAjZFgTs4cAB4AuOGlkglvDpoCeeg0d5wAPvvnIO2TqkwAeMZJmPlqgHwAFACUGnAAdGQYeOgYZIFkcAC8-nBk4WZwAIRJSQ4KoZrhWgnJqelahRFmpSlpGXAMNA7WUMGsQA) gave me no errors with that.